# K-Means Iteration failed processing output/clusters-2

Tags: java, hadoop, mahout, k-means

I just learn Hadoop for a few days, When I execute the example code from Mahout in Action in Hadoop, I get following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.InterruptedException: K-Means
>   Iteration failed processing output/clusters-2     at
>   org.apache.mahout.clustering.kmeans.KMeansDriver.runIteration(KMeansDriver.java:363)
>     at
>   org.apache.mahout.clustering.kmeans.KMeansDriver.buildClustersMR(KMeansDriver.java:310)
>     at
>   org.apache.mahout.clustering.kmeans.KMeansDriver.buildClusters(KMeansDriver.java:237)
>     at
>   org.apache.mahout.clustering.kmeans.KMeansDriver.run(KMeansDriver.java:152)
>     at mia.chapter09.KMeansExample.main(KMeansExample.java:85)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)

The code snippets

```
Path path = new Path("testdata/clusters/part-00000");
SequenceFile.Writer writer = new SequenceFile.Writer(fs, conf,
    path, Text.class, Cluster.class);

for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
  Vector vec = vectors.get(i);
  Cluster cluster = new Cluster(vec, i, new EuclideanDistanceMeasure());
  writer.append(new Text(cluster.getIdentifier()), cluster);
}
writer.close();

KMeansDriver.run(conf, new Path("testdata/points"), new Path("testdata/clusters"),
  new Path("output"), new EuclideanDistanceMeasure(), 0.001, 10,
  true, false);

SequenceFile.Reader reader = new SequenceFile.Reader(fs,
    new Path("output/" + Cluster.CLUSTERED_POINTS_DIR
             + "/part-m-00000"), conf);

IntWritable key = new IntWritable();
WeightedVectorWritable value = new WeightedVectorWritable();
while (reader.next(key, value)) {
  System.out.println(value.toString() + " belongs to cluster "
                     + key.toString());
}
reader.close();
```

Comment: make sure you format code properly while asking questions, which makes others more readable.

Answer (score 0):

It would help to specify the Mahout version u r using, along with other details like Hadoop 2.x or 1.x.

If you are using Mahout 0.7 or earlier, suggest switching over to Mahout 0.9.

Comment: precitate for your reply .I solve this problem by using maven